# Keep the number of data records but the sum of two other Variables should be calculated

Tags: sql

I have a table with Course-Participants, Course_Id and Status.
I want the number of records from Course-Participants to stay the same. But from the combination of Course_Id and Status it should show a total.
It should look like this:

[image]

And this is my attempt:

```
 SELECT     
 [Course_Id]
,Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_A
,Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_B
,Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_C 
FROM CourseParticipant
group by course_id
```

because of the group by statement, I cannot include the course participant in the query. As a result, I cannot output the desired number of data records.

Comment: Can you explain further? I am not seeing how the numbers on the right correlate to the data on the left.

Comment: Please add the tag of the database you are using to your question

Answer (score 0):

Also select `participant_id` and add it the the `group by`:

```
SELECT     
  Course_Id,
  Participant_id,
  Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_A,
  Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_B,
  Sum(case when Course_ID is not null and Status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 end) as Sum_Status_C 
FROM CourseParticipant
group by course_id, participant_id
```